# Rollback a git repository locally

Tags: git, bitbucket

Just started using git a few days ago, literally. Had no need to use it as I haven't been working in a team. Now, I can see how good it is, but I accidentally did a huge booboo.

I created a huge project locally, **initialised a repository and added everything to that repository** with `git add .` I then tried to push this to a private repository on Bitbucket I had access to, but it wouldn't accept my logins. So I was just fiddling around, and I created a branch on Bitbucket.

Create a new branch and start working locally! It says cheerily, so, without thinking, I run

```
 git fetch && git checkout branch1
```

in my terminal, without realising I'm in the directory I've been working on all day yesterday. Without a hint of a warning, git proceeds to overwrite everything in my directory with the branch I just created, the branch of course containing week-old code from the master branch.

I feel sick. I think it's just completely destroyed a weeks work. Beginner here, aright? Would you lay off the finger wagging for one second? Yes, I should have pushed more incrementally.

But remember, *I created the project locally, **initialised a repository and added everything to that repository** with `git add .`*

So does this mean I can roll back to that local repository?

I've tried running

```
git checkout .
```

but git says that it isn't a repository. Looks like game over, frankly. But how isn't a repository if it just came a pull from Bitbucket?

Here's some output

```
$  git status
# On branch ruby
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   db/
#   log/
#   tmp/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$
```

Comment: What do you get if you do a git status? Did you do a git commit after the add .?

Comment: I am a beginner, but it seems like I've completely wiped my local files. The Bitbucket repo is fine, though it's a week old.

Comment: Git won't overwrite changes you haven't committed/stashed/discarded

Comment: what does 'git branch' tell you? I think you might just need to switch branches

Comment: @whoshotjr I've updated my question..the files seem to have gone, thought I didn't commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git fetch` doesn't change your local branches and `git checkout` will simply not allow you to override uncommited changes. I personally doubt that you have caused any major damage (it's rather hard to actually lose changes)

Try doing `git checkout <branch>` where branch is the branch you committed your code on. If you don't know which branch you used, you could do `git branch` to get a list of branches and then `git checkout` each branch in turn. After each `git checkout` you should check to see if you have found your code.

Comment: Oh thank you it's all back. Thankyou all. God..that was horrible. Thankyou though

Comment: :) Glad I could help. The rule with git is that it never touches untracked files (unless you start tracking them with git add) and it doesn't let you change the state of committed files without you explicitly making a new commit using git commit or git pull. So it's hard to actually lose any change that you have committed.

Comment: In general, you would have to do something quite extraordinary in order to lose your stuff when using git. As long as something is commited it's pretty bullett-proof. (The only thing I've ever lost when using git was some untracked files, when I did something I didn't really understand..)